# Facebook page URL: is there a repository of forbidden words?

Tags: facebook, repository-pattern, facebook-page

I'm a composer/producer, and for a group of songs, I created a dedicated Facebook Page.

Now, once reached the 50 "Likes", I wanted to have an URL for each page.

But in one case it still not possible.

the tune is called "STRIPTEASE" which FB returns: it's not available.
Ok but there is not yet any page with that URL

however, I tried also

```
striptease.tune
striptease.song
```

but nothing.

To be sure it is an unique URL, I appended also the name of the band

```
striptease.tune.name_of_the_band
```

nothing ... FB tells always it's a not available address.

Thus I think there are "forbidden" words to use into addresses and probably "striptease" is one of these. Can anyone verify this please?

Thank you so much for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Easiest way would be trying with a different name than striptease, and if it works then yeah, there's probably a word filter somewhere.

Comment: Yes, I do believe there is. Following your indication, I tried also other combinations even putting dots in-between. But I think they are filtered out and the name is blocked